# IDA Pro: Platform-independent way to check if an instruction is a jump

Tags: ida, disassembly, idapython

I am looking for a way to tell if an instruction is a jump instruction. Of course, I would like to avoid checking all possible jump mnemonics for all possible CPU architectures.

I thought one may check the belonging xref type. Yet, there are several different types possible: `Code_Near_Jump` `Code_Far_Jump` but also `Data_Read` (for indirect jumps). This approach looks complicated and not very reliable to me.

For `call` instructions, there is `idaapi.is_call_insn(addr)`. Is there a similar thing for jumps?

Answer (score 4):

For ideas look at https://github.com/trailofbits/mcsema/blob/master/tools/mcsema_disass/ida/get_cfg.py

Here's an example of how to get the mnemonic of the entrypoint opcode:

```
import idaapi
import idautils

ea = idaapi.get_screen_ea()  // Gets the entrypoint VA
idautils.DecodeInstruction(ea).get_canon_mnem() // e.g. push or jne
```

I'd used that technique recently, checked the example works.
Essentially if you can get the VA of an instruction, then you can use DecodeInstruction or DecodePreviousInstruction in idautils.

Then you can use the consts that Trail of bits used e.g

```
COND_BRANCHES = [\
idaapi.NN_ja,\
idaapi.NN_jae,\
idaapi.NN_jb,
....
```

function docs here - https://www.hex-rays.com/products/ida/support/idapython_docs/

Comment: Did you try that on other platforms? I just tried it on MIPS and it did not work. If you look at the SDK, those constants seem pretty intel-specific.

Comment: I have not, however I think you are correct. See this reference for the supported ida processors https://www.hex-rays.com/products/ida/support/idadoc/618.shtml  the constants that you need for MIPS are here https://www.hex-rays.com/products/ida/support/idapython_docs/ e.g.`MIPS_null = 0
 MIPS_add = 1
 MIPS_addu = 2`

Comment: Sadly, it seems that the only way to do this is by detecting jump xrefs. I need to check, but I think it might be a problem when jumps are to non-existent addresses. Will update after checking.